# Add a property to an array based on object at the same index in a different array using Ramda

Tags: ramda.js

I have an array for example

```
const array = [
  {
    "id": 1
  },
  {
    "id": 2
  }
]
```

I want to add a new property to that based on the value at the same index in array2 using Ramda.

```
const array2 = [
  {
    0: 'Test'
  },
  {
    1: 'Test2'
  }
]
```

I want the output to be:

```
const result = [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": 'Test'
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": 'Test2'
  }
]
```

I have got to something like this so far but not sure how I map the value.

```
const fn = R.map(R.assoc('name', value??));

const result = fn(array1);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of [`R.zipWith`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#zipWith) to combine the elements at each index together from two lists using a function to determine how they're combined.

This lets you make use of [`R.assoc`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#assoc) as you had suggested to combine the two.

It will also make things simpler if you extract the value you are interested in out of the object from your `array2` elements. Without assuming much beyond what you've shared here, you can make use of [`R.map`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#map) wrapped with [`R.addIndex`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#addIndex) to provide the index when mapping over the array to extract the value associated with each index.

Combining all of this together:

```
const fn = (array, array2) => zipWith(
  assoc('name'),
  addIndex(map)((x, i) => x[i], array2),
  array,
)
```